# JPanel additional column on GUI upon run?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, 2d-games

Been working on a school project in which my group and I are making a Wheel of Fortune game with a GUI and all. When making the [panel](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcSI6Gh5RbSZ4At4fOucH_yrWyUVOP0fSg33a3Rxo5sMjpLxCcoG) for the puzzle to be displayed, I'm running into the problem of an additional column being created. It's also possible that it's just empty space, but regardless, I would like to know how to get rid of it. Here is the code for the `letterBoard` class which runs through the `wheelGUI` class.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class letterBoard extends JPanel
                            implements ActionListener                   
 {
 private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[TEXT_FIELD_COUNT];
 private Box[] boxes = new Box[SUIT_COUNT];
 private static int TEXT_FIELD_COUNT = 14;
 private static int SUIT_COUNT = 1;
 Color datGreen=new Color(0, 180, 100);

public letterBoard()
{
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
    panel.setBackground(datGreen);
    for(int t=0; t<4; t++)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < boxes.length; i++)
        {
            boxes[i] = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            for (int j=0; j< TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT; j++)
            {
                int index = i * (TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT) + j;
                fields[index] = new JTextField("   ");
                fields[index].setEditable(false);
                fields[index].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                fields[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
                panel.add(fields[index]);
                panel.add(boxes[i]);
                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,3),"WHEEL OF FORTUNE"));
            }
        }
    }
    Box b1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    b1.add(panel);
    b1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
    b1.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    add(b1);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

}
}
```

Any help in identifying the problem would be great. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5xkM.png) a picture of what it looks like upon compiling. The green bar on the right is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to pack your board container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I just miss the point, but I don't see the need for all the `Box` properties...

I simply modified the `GridLayout` to layout 14 columns as a priority over the rows and removed all the `Box` stuff...

[image]

```
public LetterBoard() {
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 14));
    panel.setBackground(datGreen);
    for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TEXT_FIELD_COUNT / SUIT_COUNT; j++) {
                int index = i * (TEXT_FIELD_COUNT / SUIT_COUNT) + j;
                fields[index] = new JTextField("   ");
                fields[index].setEditable(false);
                fields[index].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                fields[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
                panel.add(fields[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3), "WHEEL OF FORTUNE"));
    add(panel);
}
```

All the `Box` stuff was adding a extra "column" at the end of each row...